# Entity Framework Core pessimistic locking row table Mysql

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

How can I use sql query in EF Core as for example 
`this._context.Person.FirstOrDefault(a => a.id==1).ForUpdate()`

`SELECT * FROM person WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;`

in EF core  I find Implementing optimistic concurrency with EF Core(    [ConcurrencyCheck], with Fluent Api ".IsConcurrencyToken();"), but it not solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

you can use `TransactionScope` under `System.Transactions`

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
  var person = this._context.Person.FirstOrDefault(a => a.id==1);
  person.Col1 = "John Doe";
  this._context.Person.Update(person);

  this._context.SaveChanges();
  scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: I want lock one row for update but with this example, i can not do it @Simonare

Comment: TransactionScope under System.Transactions dont correspont in my case, i use beginTransaction

Answer (score 0):

To resolve my question i use this aproach:

`this._context.Person.FromSql($"SELECT * FROM person WHERE id= { personId } FOR UPDATE").FirstOrDefaultAsync();`

In Github has already been opened issue https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6717

When this issue will resolved(closed), then we can do as I want